# How to speed up ListBox population from ObservableCollection in WP app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have a WP8 Silverlight app. One of the pages contains a modified ListBox control called [ReorderListBox](https://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com) bound to an ObservableCollection through the ItemsSource property.

When the ObservableCollection has 20+ items and it is repopulated in code, the speed of the ListBox update on the screen is noticeably low. It seems, it takes 1-2 seconds when I can see the new contents.

What is the best strategy to do this very quick, without such significant delays?

Comment: I take it you have very complex items if you slow down after only 20. The best way I found in the past was to inherit from Observable Collection and create an "AddRange" method. Something like in the following link: http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/

Comment: Wrap your collection and create a lazy load

Comment: @AMR, can I find an example of that in the Internet?

Comment: I don't know, can you?

Comment: Without more detail (and code), it's difficult to make accurate suggestions as to what's causing that abnormally slow load time.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I modified my question to indicate that actually I'm using a clone of ListBox called ReorderListBox. Every list item consists of a small Path graphics (the standard check mark I got from the default CheckBox implementation), a TextBlock plus, sure, the drag handler (also enough simple Path graphics). Do you need the XAML? As for C# page code, I just assign my ObservableCollection to the ReorderListBox's ItemsSource property in the OnNavigatedTo event of the page.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Can we temporarily disable the ListBox update from the ListBox's side what can significant effect in my situation? Something as Control.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate in WinForms, but which can help in my data-bound scenario?

Comment: @AMR, Can we temporarily disable the ListBox update from the ListBox's side what can significant effect in my situation?

Comment: @AMR, found an example of [this](http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12513/data-virtualization-lazy-loading-stealth-paging-whatever-you-want-to-call-it-heres-how-to-do-it-in-silverlight). Did you mean a similar solution? In my solution, it may not help as all my data are loaded into memory from a local storage file, and my collection is bound to the ListBox which I think requests all collection items if we talk about the data part, not virtualizing UI.

Comment: Try simplifying the list items. Have you used a profiler?

Comment: @TecMan yes, that is the general topic as to which I was referring. Anything you do is going to be hand rolled so I was just suggesting some sort of lazy load pattern. There is no single solution.

Comment: @TecMan have you looked into Telerik Rad controls? I am pretty sure they have a list box that virtualizes for you

Comment: @WiredPrairie, can you give me some hints how to use a profiler (bteer free) to debug this UI control issue? I never used such a thing.

Comment: @AMR, did anyone try to bind ListBox not to an ObservableCollection? I found one interesting recipe set here: http://pelebyte.net/blog/2011/07/11/twelve-ways-to-improve-wpf-performance/

Comment: Please try searching for this information. It's easily found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj215908(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are my tips and tricks about this:

- Use VirtualizingStackPanel for the ListBox' ItemsPanel. For best results, the items should have explicitly set Height.
- Don't add 100 elements at once. Try to add them 10 at a time and then release the UI thread for a while (50-200ms), before adding another 10 and so on. Experiment with the number.
- Don't use Data Binding. Yeah, it's cool, but it's slower than setting the values manually. (Of course, binding few things is not a problem, but when you have 200 items with 10 bound properties - it can get slow.)
- Use lazy loading, as AMR suggested. The idea is to load only the items that are visible on the screen. You'll have to search the Internet for more info, though.
- Research and experiment. Is there any other way you could do this? What could make it faster/slower? IMHO trying out different strategies is very helpful generally - you learn about how things behave, some issues related to them, and what's best for one scenario, may not be optimal for another - so the more you know and have experminted with - the better.

**Edit**

One more thing:

- Simplify the Visual tree of the ItemTemplate, if possible. That's rarely an option, but it helps sometimes.

Comment: In fact, I'm using the well-known ReorderListBox control (modified the question to indicate this). I've checked it's actual visual tree, VirtualizingStackPanel is used as in the default ListBox implementation.

Comment: As for lazy loading, is it the same what VirtualizingStackPanel does?

Comment: @TecMan I think you really need to consider the other things I suggested. Especially the second one. About lazy loading - your items will not be in the list at all, until they are needed. I guess that's what was suggested. You could also load some parts of the objects/visual elements lazily, but I don't think that's really the problem.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions! I've experimented with some of them today. One of them was [RangeObservableCollection](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/) suggested by **steveg89** in the very first comment to my question. It helped to improve the situation a little bit, but not much. The fact is that even if we do AddRange, the otifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset is sent anyway. This starts to work as if we reloaded all list items, and it works bad for 20-30 items in my scenario. I'll continue my tries...